# Downgrade C# 6 code

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I have the following line of code

```
ListBox ListBox => this.AssociatedObject;
```

And the `=>` is giving me an error since I do not have C# 6.  I was wondering how this code would be implemented pre C# 6.

Would also be nice to know what the terminology is for the `=>` operator, I have no clue what to google for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The terminology for `=>` in this case is called an "Expression Body"

Comment: @CameronAavik It's tough trying to figure stuff out yourself when you don't know what keywords to search for. thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is the way a read-only property can be written, so you would just do this in earlier versions:

```
ListBox ListBox { get { return this.AssociatedObject; } }
```